# Differ database library names (artifacts) for various maven profiles (jboss,tomcat,glassfish) in Maven, Artifactory and Jenkins environment

Tags: maven, tomcat, jboss, jenkins, artifactory

We have CI Jenkins jobs configured to build for various maven profiles.
Each compiled library goes into Artifactory libs-release or libs-snapshots virtual repository depending on its version.

Now we have problems how to configure builds for "Jboss" and "Tomcat" maven profiles.
Each of those two profiles will produce database libraries specific for each one (jboss or tomcat) with the exact same names. How to organize/configure environment to differ those libraries for each environment (jboss or tomcat)? To put it more simple... how to know for each profile which library/artifactory is the right one to use from remote repository from Artifactory?

Hope you understand the question :)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023836/now-getting-401-unauthorized-in-jenkins-when-deploying-artifact-to-archiva-maven/14024843#14024843

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to the rescue. On the producing side you need to [set different classifiers based on profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196569/change-deployed-artifact-name-based-on-profile). On the consuming side you need to define different dependencies based on the profile. In Jenkins you'll run the correct profile by specifing -p in "Goals and options" textfield in job configuration.